# CSS positioning/size

Tags: css

I am using `@media all and (max-width: 600px) {}` in my css for responsive menu, the thing is that it does not show correctly.

[image]

I want the orange fill the green space.. and turn the green space to transparant of course. Basically it's just a size/position problem.

**CSS:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

  .example-header .container { 
     width: auto; 
     height:auto; 
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:auto;
  }
  /*Zwarte  MENU balk */
  a.menu-link { 
     display: block; 
     color: #fff; 
     background-color: #333;  
     text-decoration: none; 
     padding: 19px 10px; 
     width:auto; 
     height:auto; 
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:auto;
     margin-bottom:2em;
  }
  .menu { 
     border-top: 10px solid #333;
     border-bottom:10px solid #333;     
     height:13.2em; 
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:auto;
     width:100%;
     background-color:blue;
  }  
  .menu ul { 
     width:auto; 
     height:auto;  
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:auto;
  }
  .menu > ul { 
     height:auto;   
     margin-top:; 
     background-color:TRANSPARANT;
  }
  .menu li, .menu > ul > li { 
     width:100%;
     height:auto; 
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:0px;
     background-color:green;
  }  
  .menu li a { 
     color: #000;
     display: inline; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #333; 
     position: relative; 
     height:auto; 
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:auto;
     background-color:orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the corresponding HTML look?

Comment: its a CMS, can't really link it here I am afraid! I can check what I can do

Comment: Send us html of your menu, just copy from your code or developer tool.

Comment: Share a fiddle of your code to get best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a padding-related issue, try setting it to 0 instead of auto for `.menu ul`. HTML would be helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the anchor elements' should be `display: block;` instead of `display: inline;`. And possibly their margin should also be just `0` instead of `0 auto`

Can't say much without the HTML.